# Непереведенные и ошибочные строки для незарегистрированных пользователей

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Попробовал зайти незарегистрированным пользователем. Нашел пару ошибок.

1. На мете показывается такой блок:

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. При попытке оставить комментарий: подозреваю, что должно быть «50» или «**50**», но не «**50**». Или даже «Чтобы комментировать, нужно зарегистрироваться на сайте [и получить 50 баллов репутации].»

   > [image: **50** баллов репутации]
3. На странице нового вопроса.

   > [image: неверная подсказка про почту]

Должно быть как-то так:

> обязательна, но показана не будет